# writing unit tests against a treeview

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, tdd

I have something like the following in a viewModel in a silverlight applicaiton:

```
 public void OnSelectedItemChanged(TreeView treeView)
    {
        if (treeView.SelectedItem is Customer)
        {
            var customer = treeView.SelectedItem as Customer;

            if (customer.IsSpecial)
            {
                treeView.SelectItem(specialNode);
              ...
        }
    }
```

Never mind the logic (it only for demonstration). The application works fine. My question is strictly realated to writing a unit test for this method. I can not seems to create a test harness to use where I can successfully do things like SelectedItem or SelectItem. In otherwords I would need to do things like this in my setup.

```
 TreeView tv = new TreeView();
 var item = new TreeViewItem();

 tv.ItemsSource = new List<object> { item };
 tv.SelectItem(item); // does not work
```

Is there any way to test this method?

Comment: Could you write automated UI tests?

Comment: This is one big reason for using MVVM in Silverlight, WPF, etc. -- testability. With a code-only viewmodel to which UI elements bind, we can test all the logic without concerning ourselves with UI elements at all.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase the question then - In my viewmodel I have a ICommand that the view binds to (using the SelectedItemChanged event as a source). Now how do I test the command? The command IS the code I show above.

Answer (score -1):

Unit tests are usually to test a single unit of code that's a single functionality and is mainly useful for confirming business logic.

There are UI based testing frameworks available, you may want to look into that. Or you could use automated UI testing frameworks like ROBOT.

Saying that, if you are trying to unit test your tree view then that might be a sign of not correctly modular code, you should be able to take out unit test based code in a separate function and unit test that function. If that's not possible then you most probably don't need unit test.

Comment: I disagree. Try to include the whole system in your tests. Only when that becomes too blunt should you test smaller parts. Besides, the ViewModel in WPF is perfect for testing.

Comment: A single unit test should NEVER try to test the whole system, that's what integration testing is for. In case you were pointing to unit test coverage then the ideal number is around 80% coverage, going for 100% coverage just menas too many useless tests.

Comment: In that case, prefer writing what Beenish calls integration tests (but exclude external systems, like the database). Testing small parts leads to a fragile design where your tests hinder refactorings instead of enabling them. Also, I recommend not measuring code coverage.

Comment: Unit tests are the measure of quality of every system. No unit tests mean no quality. Unit and integration tests are two different things needed for two different goals. @Kalin, I would suggest you to read up on unit tests :).

Comment: I started practicing TDD about a decade ago. And I used to have an opinion similar to yours. But let's just say that we disagree and leave it at that.